# Flexbox wrap - Skip the first element

Tags: css, flexbox

How do I use the flexbox wrap feature to skip the first element? I have a fiddle which explains everything properly:

https://jsfiddle.net/adityarb88/3ca1m1un/

```
.form-group{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  label{
    flex: 0 0 200px;
    margin: 0.5 rem;
  }

  input{
    flex: 1 auto;
    max-width: 200px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

I want the input text boxes to wrap but not below the label. Is that possible?

Comment: If you want to change HTML https://jsfiddle.net/3ca1m1un/2/

Comment: What i mean is that the input boxes should wrap but they shouldn't appear below the label. All input boxes should be aligned and wrap below each other. The fiddle what nenad shared is what i want. Can that be done without that extra div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change your markup, you could do like this.

And to make it more responsive, I added a media query.

```css
.form-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 150px;
}
.form-group label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 150px;
}
.form-group input {
  flex: 1 auto;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 380px) {

  .form-group {
    padding-left: 10px;
  }

  .form-group label {
    position: relative;
    flex: 1 auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Test Label</label>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</form>
```